# PostScript: Fixing rounding error in floating point number

Tags: postscript

I am trying to make an axis with tick marks labeled with numbers. Everything is working fine except for the last number generated for the axis is 0.099999 instead of 0.1. I have removed the line drawing parts from my code below, but left the part that generates the numbers. These are the numbers that I get from the below code: 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.09999999 (should be 0.01). Is there anyway to round numbers or calculate the numbers a different way to avoid the rounding error?

```
/str 10 string def
/count 0 def
/totalUnits 1 def
/ticks 0.1 def

totalUnits ticks neg 0
{
/loopnum exch def
loopnum 10 str cvrs
/stringnumber exch def % string representing the number
/count count 0.1 add def
} for
```

Comment: Not familiar with postscript, but in other languages, one can use integers (fixed point representation) for your numbers - in this case x10, so that the values are perfectly stored.  Then you can just print out the decimal point yourself on print.  Basically, store 1 for 0.1, 2 for 0.2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you can use integers to avoid this quirk of floating-point numbers.

```
/str 10 string def 
/count 0 def 
/scaling .1 def 

10 -1 1{
    scaling mul 
    10 string cvs 
    %dup =
    /stringnumber exch def 
    /count count 1 add def 
} for
```

This same rounding issue affects all languages that use a binary floating-point representation for numbers since the fraction 1/10 has a repeatinging pattern in its binary representation. It's the same effect that gives you .333333... for 1/3 in decimal representation. Summing up these quantities loses bits from the bottom where the (input) values have been truncated.

Comment: So basically you are claiming that division (multiplication by 0.1) is exact while addition is not? Actually it works, but are you just lucky? Shouldn't the code use proper rounding instead?

Comment: Addition of integers is exact. That's the trick here: moving the conversion to floating point numbers to the inside of the loop, so the loop control has nice integers to iterate over.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look close enough: While you are applying `scaling` in each loop iteration, it's not based on the previous result, but in the integer loop variable. So errors cannot accumulate.